# Change the color (material) of the face depending on the distance

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I need to set a particular material on the face of the mesh, depending on the distance between the center (or the nearest to "empty" vertex) of the face and the "Empty" so that the mesh gradually changes its color (material) as the "Empty" approaches.

I feel intuitive that I need to place the nodes "Position" and "Capture Attribute" somewhere, but I do not understand where to put them to work. The options I tried were unsuccessful.

[image]

Оfftopic:
I do not understand why geometry nodes being such a complex system, it has such a poor description. And all training is based on short, unrelated articles and video instructions from different parts of the Internet, which do not allow you to see the overall picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this task as follows:

[image]

Here I first convert the instance of the *Empty* into points, because only at this point I get a geometry with which the node `Geometry Proximity` can work.

If you would not do this, there would be no geometry to compare the positions with, because an *Empty* has no mesh.

After that you only need to compare the distance as usual and choose your material accordingly.

[image]

---

By the way, I don't think the *Geometry Nodes* documentation is too bad. I just think that there are way too many bloated video tutorials that you can't efficiently learn how to use.

Each node has its own tasks. It's like programming: Each command does something very specific. But with time you learn which things do what exactly, and above all you learn only by trying, in which combination which results can be achieved.

Don't get discouraged! Let the creativity run free and just keep going ... the rest comes by itself.

Comment: and my intuition has fully failed me :D